# How change the Firebase project for an app on flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I got an android app developed on flutter in production and Play Store, I used a Firebase Project ("A") with this app for FCM, Analytics and Crashlytics, without any database, now I created a new Firebase Project ("B"), and I submit a version to the Play Store in test with this new Project configurating the google-servises.json and with the flutterfire cofigure command, but when I go to the play store I can not upgrade app, because raise the following error in the LogCat:

2022-12-01 10:20:36.643 22232-22232/? E/Finsky: [2] nfx.e(2): Submitter: commit error message INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package cl.alfa.myapp signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!

and in the play store, says that the app can not be upgrated.

How can I change the Firebase project for the app succesfully, I dont care if I lose the history in  the other project, but I dont want that the users has to uninstall the previous app, I want that they can upgrade their app succesfully.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

I am expecting that the users can upgrade the app succesfully.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you are trying to install a lower version of the signed app. You need to increase the version number. Or if you want to force install use this command. It is doing the installation with downgrade ability.

Command - **adb install -d <path to APK file>**

Android Debug Bridge(ADB) install command doc - **https://adbshell.com/commands/adb-install**